# Deploy to AWS Private Subnet from AzureDevops

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, azure-devops, aws-fargate

Im trying to add a pipeline to Azure Devops that pushes my code updates to AWS private subnet. My app runs on AWS Fargate.

Don't see any options to do this.

Would like to automatically deploy to my AWS website.

Comment: Hi, how is your deploy pipeline going? Can you deploy app to AWS successfully now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your code to AWS, at first, you must create the **service connection** with AWS with a set of your valid AWS credentials. You can follow this doc [AWS Tools for Microsoft VSTS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) to get more details about build this service connection.

[image]

And then, you still need to install some extension to Azure Devops so that you can use task which related to AWS: [AWS Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools) and [AWS S3 Upload](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MFelling.AWSS3Upload). The previous extension which named AWS Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Services can enable you to use such as **AWS command**, **AWS Shell Script** to execute command in AWS. And, with AWS S3 Upload, you can deploy files to AWS.

In pipeline, add the tasks to build your repos as normal. And then login to your AWS account with AWS cli task, copy your build solution and upload them to AWS. For more details, I recommand you check this blog: [Deploy app to AWS](https://medium.com/@wicaksono.nugi/deploy-asp-net-core-app-to-aws-eb-running-a-linux-using-azure-devops-part-2-cf6e147de014).